# Exception CX_SY_REF_IS_INITAL

Tags: abap

I'm setting up a Method call from a class

```
DATA: r_info TYPE REF TO zcl_sv_job_offline_ctrl.


 CALL METHOD r_info->create
    EXPORTING
         is_data   = lr_test_record.
```

And receiving the following errors:

```
CX_SY_REF_IS_INITAL

You are trying to access a component with a 'ZERO' object reference (points to nothing). Variable: "R_INFO".
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Cross-referencing your question in SCN (there are some answers): https://answers.sap.com/questions/12905378/you-are-trying-to-access-a-component-with-a-zero-o.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have the rep to comment just yet...
I notice that your class is a Z so I'm wondering if you are trying to create a singleton class. In which case. Your 'Create' should be static. Your Constructor private and your Instance in a private attribute. 
From the other comments, I agree, your question is missing some key details to provide an accurate answer.
If `IO_DISPATCHER` is part of the constructor and you are unable to pass a value, you need to dig a little deeper into the purpose of the class. See if you can give it what it wants. Try a 'where used' and check out the other usages of the class. You might find you are looking at the wrong class, or at least approaching from the wrong direction.
If `create` is some method on the class and it is not static then you will never get it to work until you create an instance of the class.
Another thought that comes to mind is that you might be in the right place and just doing the wrong thing. Check your globals to see if there is already an instance of the class and you are trying to access something via declaration as data rather than using the global instance?? 
All guess work without more details.

Answer (score 6):

You missed to create the object. 
so you need to to:

`create object r_info.`

or

`r_info = new zcl_sv_job_offline_ctrl( ).`

or if there is a "factory method" ( what your 'create' method indicates )

`r_info = zcl_sv_job_offline_ctrl=>create( is_data   = lr_test_record ).`

Your Exception tells you that the reference ( r_info ) is not connected with an object on the heap. So you need to do one of the above steps and then it should work. ( depending on your class )

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create the Object (No value was passed to the mandatory parameter "IO_DISPATCHER".  Also,the method is a redefinition so => doesn't work.

Comment: And where is this magical `IO_DISPATCHER` in your question? In your example you declare a reference `r_info` and then call a method on it without instantiating it, so Sasku's answer is correct.

Comment: We don't know the whole definition of your class. especially we don't have the definition of the constructor. As far as I can see the error message shows, that you need to pass something to the parameter io_dispatcher while creating the object ( so in the constructor ).

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look how ABAP-OO and how constructors ( as well es the creation of objects ) work. You could find something in [this](https://www.sap-press.com/object-oriented-programming-with-abap-objects_3597/) sap press book.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

The solution was simply to instantiate the parent classes (properly), enabled me to instantiate the class in question.